# Assigning a lambda as a parameter to a generic method called through reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, lambda, closures

Consider a generic method as follow:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public static void SomeMethod<T>(Func<T>);
}
```

I would like to call this method using reflection. This is how far I could make it:

```
_SomeMethod = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
Type type = typeof(SomeType); //Actually SomeType is extracted using reflection and it's not fixed
MethodInfo toBeCalled = _SomeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
toBeCalled.Invoke(null, () => obj);
```

But it gives compile error:

```
Error CS1660: Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type `object' (CS1660)
```

Which is absolutely acceptable but what's the work around?

Please keep in mind that the **closure** created using the lambda is something that I need, so don't eliminate it.

**[UPDATE]**

To clarify the situation so it makes sense; the functor created using the lambda is an instantiator used by `SomeMethod` to create an instance of the class `SomeType`. But I don't want to actually create the object in functor, instead return it from a collection of instantiated objects from before. The easiest way would be having the `obj` in a closure returned by the lambda, don't you think?

Comment: Well what's the type of `obj`? If you don't know the `T` involved, it's hard to see how you can create a `Func<T>` from a lambda expression. Are you always just returning a constant value, or would you sometimes have other lambda expressions? More information would be really helpful.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question

Comment: But you want to create a `Func` which always just returns `obj`? Nothing more complicated than that, ever? You say you want to keep the closure - does that mean you're going to change the value of `obj` afterwards? Again, more clarity would be really helpful.

Comment: Can we change `SomeMethod()`?

Comment: @JamesCurran No, actually `SomeMethod` belongs to a library and I didn't write it!

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added a scenario. What do you think? Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: @Mehran: It's still not entirely clear, to be honest. I'll add an answer, and you can see whether it helps.

Comment: @Mehran is my suggestion close to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you a looking to pass known object ot generic method that takes `Func<T>` and that "func" is always identity. One more wrapper may help:

```
public void SomeMethodInvokerRuntime(Type typeofSomeClass, object obj)
{
    var _SomeMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethodInvoker", 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    MethodInfo toBeCalled = _SomeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType());
    toBeCalled.Invoke(null, new[]{typeofSomeClass, obj});
}

public static void SomeMethodInvoker<T>(Type typeofSomeClass, T obj)
{
    var _SomeMethod = typeofSomeClass.GetMethod("SomeMethod",
          BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    MethodInfo toBeCalled = _SomeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
    Func<T> that = () => obj; // Main part - strongly typed delegate
    toBeCalled.Invoke(null, new[]{that});
}
```

Sample usage:

```
static class Test
{
    public static void SomeMethod<T>(Func<T> f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((T)(f()));
    }
}

SomeMethodInvoker(typeof(Test), 3);
object obj = "test";

SomeMethodInvokerRuntime(typeof(Test), obj);
```

Alternatively you can build expression and compile into a function as shown in [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31481381/477420).

Comment: PS  I may post sample for expression approacy if this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: The problem is you have `Type typeofSomeClass`, but not `T obj`.  `T` needs to be set at compile time, but we don't know it until runtime.

Comment: @JamesCurran but you already know how to call generic function with unknown type (`MakeGenericMethod` on SomeMethodInvoker and pass `methodInfoOfSomeMethodInvoker.Invoke(null, obj)`), so I assume that the only problem is how to build `Func<some-run-time-type>`... Would that provide complete answer?

Comment: Ignore this answer - Jon Skeet awaited long enough :) and posted awesome answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I like yours better. It's much simpler and easier to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, why I have to do this Func<T> that = (Func<T>)(() => (T)obj); toBeCalled.Invoke(null, new object[]{that});. Otherwise, VS will complain about the code?

Comment: @Helic lambda itself does not have type that it can be infer type at compile time - it must be either treated as Expression or delegate and you need external to lambda hint on which on to chose - which is where casting to `(Func<T>)` or assigning to `Func<T>` helps. Indeed if type of `obj` is `object` you need additional cast to `T` so `()=>obj` actually have chance to be cast to `Func<T>` successfully.

Comment: @Mehran I've updated code so it actually close to syntactically correct and doing what you looking for..

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound like you really need a lambda expression here. You can build a function to return a constant value very easily using expression trees:

```
var expression = Expression.Constant(obj, type);
var delegateType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var func = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expression).Compile();
toBeCalled.Invoke(null, func);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduced to it's simplest form, we have this:

```
void Main()
{
    MethodInfoInvoke(()=> {} );
}

void MethodInfoInvoke(object func)
{
}
```

Which fails with the same error.

Now, if we pass the lambda in a delegate, it seems happier:

```
void Main()
{
    Object obj = new Object();
    Func<object> action = ()=> obj; ;
    MethodInfoInvoke(action);      // accepted!
}
```

Comment: Your reduction is not proper. You can not reduce having `SomeMethod<T>(Func<T>)`, introduce such a method and try calling it with a lambda as the parameter using reflection and then you'll see the problem. Your current solution does not work then.